# How to pass dynamic fields Query to database using WSO2ESB OR WSO2DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I want to pass my query to database for retrieving the column.  I am passing dynamic columns using ESB my configuration is like this

```
 <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="dbl3" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">   <target>
         <inSequence>
            <property name="A" value="select e_name,e_address from emp where " scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="B" expression="//fieldname/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="C" expression="//fieldvalue/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="D" value="=" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="E" expression="concat(get-property('A'),get-property('B'),get-property('D'),get-property('C'))" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <dblookup>
               <connection>
                  <pool>
                     <password>Youtility11</password>
                     <user>youtilitydba</user>
                     <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample</url>
                     <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                  </pool>
               </connection>
               <statement>
                  <sql>get-property('E')</sql>
                  <result name="ee" column="e_name"/>
               </statement>
            </dblookup>
            <log level="custom">
               <property name="AA" expression="get-property('A')"/>
               <property name="BB" expression="get-property('B')"/>
               <property name="CC" expression="get-property('C')"/>
               <property name="DD" expression="get-property('ee')"/>
               <property name="EE" expression="get-property('E')"/>
            </log>
         </inSequence>
         <outSequence>
                <send/>
             </outSequence>   </target>   <description></description> </proxy>
```

My output like this:

```
EE = select e_name,e_address from emp where e_address=thane
EE = select e_name,e_address from emp where e_no=5
```

Based on input values query will generate, how can I pass the above query to the database?
My error is like this:

```
[2013-01-24 14:22:32,743] ERROR - DBLookupMediator Error executing statement : get-property('E') against DataSource : jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "get"
 Position: 1
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.db.DBLookupMediator.processStatement(DBLookupMediator.java:46)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.db.AbstractDBMediator.mediate(AbstractDBMediator.java:143)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:60)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:154)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processXMLRequest(RESTUtil.java:89)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.RESTUtil.processPOSTRequest(RESTUtil.java:189)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:411)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:268)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: how we can pass the variable to sql statement or database ...using wso2 esb

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't pass a SQL statement to the "`<sql/>`" element of the DBLookup/DBReport mediators using "get-property" construct. Besides, I believe what you're trying to do is sort of a hack to pass variables to a SQL query. The proper way of doing this should be by using WSO2 Data Services Server. Please refer the documentation of WSO2 DSS [1] which provides you with a comprehensive guide on how to use it to achieve your data manipulative tasks with its rich set of features offered to the users.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DSS301/WSO2+Data+Services+Server+Documentation

Comment: It doesn't seem like DSS can handle this much better. Here's a [semi-recent blog post demonstrating how dynamic queries are supported in DSS](http://mycodeideas.blogspot.com/2016/07/wso2-dss-dynamic-sql-query.html). Basically the dynamic SQL query parts are passed as HTTP query string parameters and it warns of SQL injection attacks. Not a clean solution at all :(